# Average word length of input file

Tags: shell, unix

If i use

```
wc -m filename
```

it will generate the number of characters

and

`wc -w filename`

will generate number of words

if i used this info by dividing number of characters/number of words

it will give me misleading result as number of character will include spaces and punctuation

any advice ?

Answer (score 3):

the solution that I came up with without writing a script was to pipe it through a couple of commands like this.

```
<filename  tr -d " \t\n\r\.\?\!" | wc -m
```

This works to remove all of the spacing, like new line, tabs and normal spacing. A more rigorous `tr` command that included any sort of other punctuation like a colon can just be added to the list for example \:

Hope That Helps

Answer (score 2):

Subtract out characters you do not want

```
 chars=$(tr -dc '[:alnum:]' < filename | wc -c)
 words=$(cat filename | wc -c)
```

Now do you calculation.  I piped into wc to avoid the extra "filename" in output

```
printf "%.2f" $(echo "$chars/$words" | bc -l)
```

Edit: thanks BMW

Comment: should be :  words=$(cat filename | wc -w)  , not wc -m

Comment: it give 0 in all result!